# Select n records from an arbitrary week dataset template given start day-of-week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset containing a 'template' of 7 day's worth of data (basically timestamp and value) in 30 minute time steps.  What I need is to be able to provide a start day-of-week and time and to return exactly n records representing consecutive days of the week.

For example if I want 3 day's data beginning 3:00 PM on Satutrday I need to begin with the data in my template where day-of-week is Satutrday and time 3:00 PM; select up to 144 records; then I have to go back to the first record in my dataset template and select the remaining records so that my result is Saturday through Monday.

Easy in code but can I have SQL Server do this for me (I'm not so familiar with complex SQL operations)?

Comment: Can you put up what the table is defined like, some example of data in it, and what the desired result would be like?

Comment: You say it's a template table. How do you specify the `timestamp`? I mean, is it a `datetime` (with some arbitrary starting date), or an `int = weekday` + a `datetime` without the date part, or something else? I've got some basic approach in mind, but it might be better to post it taking into account the actual design.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restrict it to N number of records with something like this:

```
SELECT TOP(<NRecords>) <Your Fields> FROM <YourTable>
    WHERE <TimeStampField> BETWEEN '<SartDateTime>' AND '<EndDateTime>'
```

Replace all `<Name>` items with your values. You could extend this and make it a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) where you then only have to pass in the N value and the start and end times.